# Override mail.app default css stylesheet used to display messages

Tags: safari, mail.app, email

I see there are workarounds to override the default stylesheet in Safari but I am trying to do the same in the mail.app
I tried:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail UserStyleSheetEnabled 1
defaults write com.apple.mail UserStyleSheetLocationURLString "~/maillocal.css"
defaults write com.apple.mail WebKitUserStyleSheetEnabledPreferenceKey 1
defaults write com.apple.mail WebKitUserStyleSheetLocationPreferenceKey "~/maillocal.css"
```

But it doesn't work. Anyone manage to get around it on Big Sur 11.6?

Comment: Is there any information available that this *should* work in Mail at all?

Comment: @nohillside Only some random posts over the internet.